# What is this folding camera with pronounced angular or beveled corners?

Tags: medium-format, camera-identification

I would love to know what camera this is:

[image: camera to identify]

This picture is a detail from a large poster representing a photographer at work on the occasion of an exhibition of his works. I took it 14 years ago and always wanted to identify it.

It looks like it might be a medium format but it could de a large format too, it's hard to tell because of perspective.

Comment: Who is the photographer that is the subject of the poster? That might be useful information to help identify the camera type.

Comment: I would have included it if I could remember, but unfortunately my memory isn't that good...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a [Linhof Super Technika IV 6×9](https://cameraquest.com/lint369.htm). (Usage rights of photos at cameraquest.com do not allow reuse of images, so I can't upload an image here).

Comment: he's right it's a Linhof Technika 6x9